# mutate rowSums exclude one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this

```
> df
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

      a x y z
1 name1 1 1 1
2 name2 1 1 1
3 name3 1 1 1
4 name4 1 1 1
```

Want to mutate it by adding columns x, y, and z (there can be many more numeric columns). Trying to exclude column 'a' as follows is not working.

```
dft <- df %>% mutate(funs(total = rowSums(.)), -a)
Error: not compatible with STRSXP
```

This also produces an error:

```
dft <- df %>% mutate(total = rowSums(.), -a)
Error in rowSums(.) : 'x' must be numeric
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to keep non-numeric columns in the result, you can do this:

```
dat %>% mutate(total=rowSums(.[, sapply(., is.numeric)]))
```

**UPDATE:** Now that `dplyr` has [scoped versions](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/scoped.html) of its standard verbs, here's another option:

```
dat %>% mutate(total=rowSums(select_if(., is.numeric)))
```

**UPDATE 2:** With [`dplyr 1.0`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/rowwise.html#per-row-summary-statistics), the approaches above will still work, but you can also do row sums by combining `rowwise` and `c_across`:

```
iris %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(row.sum = sum(c_across(where(is.numeric))))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use rich selectors with `select()` inside the call to `rowSums()`

```
df %>% transmute(a, total = rowSums(select(., -a)))
```

Comment: I think this is the most general answer and it works in case you want to remove a numerical column as well. It could also be written as `df %>% mutate(total = rowSums(select(., -a)))`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#dummy data    
df <- read.table(text="a x y z

1 name1 1 1 1
2 name2 1 1 1
3 name3 1 1 1
4 name4 1 1 1",header=TRUE)

library(dplyr)

df %>% select(-a) %>% mutate(total=rowSums(.))
```

First exclude text column - `a`, then do the `rowSums` over remaining numeric columns.

Comment: I tried that, but then the resulting data frame misses column a. I want to keep it. Is adding back the only option?

Comment: @user3949008 see eipi10's answer, which keeps the column `a`.